# DataHub: issue with getting lineage between Looker and Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, looker

For some reason does not build lineage between Looker and Snowflake. I use the following recipe configs.

LookML:

```
source:
    type: lookml
    config:
        parse_table_names_from_sql: true
        stateful_ingestion:
            enabled: true
        api:
            client_secret: '${DEVELOPMENT_LOOKER_R_CLIENT_SECRET}'
            client_id: '${DEVELOPMENT_LOOKER_R_CLIENT_ID}'
            base_url: 'https://healthunion.looker.com'
        github_info:
            deploy_key: ""
            repo: ''
        extract_column_level_lineage: true
pipeline_name: 'pname'
```

Looker:

```
source:
    type: looker
    config:
        base_url: ''
        client_secret: '${DEVELOPMENT_LOOKER_R_CLIENT_SECRET}'
        client_id: '${DEVELOPMENT_LOOKER_R_CLIENT_ID}'
        extract_column_level_lineage: true
        extract_usage_history: true
        extract_owners: true
pipeline_name: 'pname'
```

Snowflake:

```
source:
    type: snowflake
    config:
        account_id: ''
        warehouse: ANALYST_MD
        username: '${DEVELOPMENT_SNOWFLAKE_RW_USER}'
        password: '${DEVELOPMENT_SNOWFLAKE_RW_PASSWORD}'
        role: el_role
        include_column_lineage: true
        include_views: true
        include_tables: true
pipeline_name: 'pname'
```

ChatGPT recommends to use the next options:

Enable lineage tracking: Once you have established the relationship between the Snowflake and Looker metadata, you can enable lineage tracking for both sources. This will allow DataHub to track the flow of data from Snowflake to Looker and vice versa.

To enable lineage tracking, you need to set the extract_column_level_lineage parameter to true for both Snowflake and Looker ingestion sources. Additionally, you need to make sure that both sources are ingested under the same pipeline name, as I mentioned in my previous response.

Additionally, your LookML ingestion source config is missing the include_views parameter, which could cause issues with lineage tracking. You should include include_views: true in your LookML source config.

it's unclear whether you have set up the schema mapping between Snowflake and Looker metadata. Without this mapping, DataHub may not be able to correctly link the tables and columns between the two sources.

Establish the relationship between Snowflake and Looker metadata: To connect the metadata from Snowflake and Looker, you can use the "schema mapping" feature provided by DataHub. This feature allows you to map the Snowflake database and table names to the corresponding Looker model and explore names.

To set up the schema mapping, you can use the tablePrefix and namePrefix parameters in the Snowflake ingestion source config, and the model_name and explore_name parameters in the Looker ingestion source config. Make sure that the prefixes and names match between the two sources to ensure proper mapping.

Note that I've also included a metadata section with a metadataTransformers array and a schemaMetadataHandler transformer. This is used to extract metadata from the sources and transform it into a format that DataHub can understand.

But it's crazy advice and it doesn't work.